# how to prevent other app to bind to my service

Tags: android, ipc, android-service-binding

I can find the way to setup Bound Services in [android AIP Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger)!

This demo allows any app to bind to it.But what I want is only my apk can communicate with the service I code.Is there any way to do it? How to?
Thanks!

Comment: I solve it using aidl at last

Answer (score 1):

Services are not exported by default, meaning they can only be called/bound by your application. Unless you add `android:exported="true"` to your service's manifest entry, only your app will be able to bind to the service.

Comment: Yes,I know this.In my case,I want to publish a apk with only a service.This apk may have special permission, e.g. inject key

Answer (score 0):

`Service.onBind()` receives intent that was used to bind to your service. One approach is to add an *permission* extra to the aforementioned intent, check for its value in `Service.onBind()`, and deny any bind requests in case of invalid permission value.

Comment: I can add some flag on intent, but the other developer may add the same flag.

Comment: How do they know what is the value of the permission if you're the only one who sets it?

Comment: If I want to know a intent's detail, I would make a new service to  catch intent.<service android:name="com.example.airaddon.airService" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.airaddon.airService"></action>
      </intent-filter> 
        </service>

Comment: Let me clarify the idea: 1) you [create an intent for a specific component](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29) and add permission extra to it; 2) `bindService()` is passed this "targeted" `Intent` and no other receiver can catch it; 3) service checks if _permission_ is valid